# Adding space between Strings in Array

Tags: java, string, javafx

I want to display an array of Strings with space between words like this:

> One Two Three

I have tried this:

> Display.setText( " " + swappedString);

But if i do it that way, the first word will have space before it. I don't want that space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Java 8 we can use

```
String joined = String.join(" ", yourStringArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this simple solution :

```
String []inputStr = {"One","Two","Three"};
StringBuilder resultStr = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.length; i++) {
   if (i > 0) {
      resultStr.append(" ");
    }
   resultStr.append(inputStr[i]);
}

System.out.println(resultStr.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also :

```
String [] myArray = {"One","Two","Three"};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String value : myArray) {
builder.append(value).append(" ");
}
System.out.println(builder);
```

Comment: Don't do `append(value+" ")`. Write it as `append(value).append(" ")`. `value+" "` would need to create new StringBuilder to concatenate these values which we don't need since we already have one created.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **trim()** function of String to get rid of extra space (before or after) in the space.

See the sample code to get how it works:

```
        String result = "";
        String[] strings = new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"};
        for (String string : strings) {
            result = result + string + " ";
        }
        result = result.trim();
        System.out.println(">" + result + ">");
```

One outside suggesation is, use StringBuilder. It does not create object every time.Sample Code:

```
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String[] strings = new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"};
        for (String string : strings) {
            stringBuilder.append(string);
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
        }
        String result = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        System.out.println(">" + result + ">");
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pointing out the obvious:

```
Display.setText(swappedString + " ");
```

This does, however, add a space at the end of the String.